# Router ignores this.props.children when routes are imported but not when inline

Tags: express, reactjs, browserify, react-router, isomorphic-javascript

## Introduction

I am attempting to create an **Isomorphic** ReactJS application using React-Router and ExpressJS. This requires some modularity so both client and server has access to specific scripts such as the routes. The modularity is achieved through Browserify and the router guides I have followed are [react-router lesson server rendering](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/13-server-rendering) and [react-router guide server rendering](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/ServerRendering.md).

---

## Problem

The router behaves differently when routes are imported from an external **routes.jsx** as opposed to being written in the same file as the router. The **this.props.children** is ignored when the routes are imported and the view replaces the whole app, while is honored when in the routes are in the same file and replaces only the subsection of the app (desired outcome).

---

## Example

#### routes.jsx - For both server and client

```js
import React from 'react';
import {Route, IndexRoute, Redirect} from 'react-router';

/* Base */
import App from './client.jsx';

/* Views */
import HomeView from '_view/HomeView';
import WorkView from '_view/WorkView';

const Routes = (
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={HomeView} />
    <Redirect from="home" to="/" component={HomeView} />
    <Route path="work" component={WorkView} />
  </Route>
);

export default Routes;
```

---

#### client.jsx - Imported routes

When using imported Routes the whole of `<main>` is replaced with eg. HomeView rather than just `{this.props.children}`.

```js
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import {Router, browserHistory} from 'react-router';

/* Routes */
import Routes from './routes.jsx';

/* Components */
import Header from '_component/Header';

/* Views */
import HomeView from '_view/HomeView';
import WorkView from '_view/WorkView';

export default class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <main>
        <Header />
        {this.props.children}
      </main>
    )
  }
}

if(typeof window !== 'undefined' && typeof document !== 'undefined') {
  render(<Router history={browserHistory} routes={Routes} />,
    document.getElementById('root'));
}
```

---

#### client.jsx - Inline routes

When using inline Routes only `{this.props.children}` is replaced with eg. HomeView. However this removes the modularity and the server can no longer reach the routes. This means either export the routes from **client.jsx** or have two copies of the same rules. Neither of which I find appealing.

```js
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import {Router, Route, IndexRoute, Redirect, browserHistory} from 'react-router';

/* Components */
import Header from '_component/Header';

/* Views */
import HomeView from '_view/HomeView';
import WorkView from '_view/WorkView';

export default class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <main>
        <Header />
        {this.props.children}
      </main>
    )
  }
}

const Routes = (
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={HomeView} />
    <Redirect from="home" to="/" component={HomeView} />
    <Route path="work" component={WorkView} />
  </Route>
);

if(typeof window !== 'undefined' && typeof document !== 'undefined') {
  render(<Router history={browserHistory} routes={Routes} />,
    document.getElementById('root'));
}
```

---

## Question

Where does the error lie? With my code, with react-router, or with browserify's export method?

Comment: There is a circular reference,maybe here is the problem

Comment: That was a concern of mine I will try to seperate them and se if that solved the issue. Doesnt seem like that would be the cause of the issue but I wont dismiss it until I have tried it :)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my inexperience with browserify caused this issue. As always with code it can be hard to debug what goes wrong but the answer was simple:

> There is a circular reference,maybe here is the problem – gu mingfeng

Thank you, stackoverflow!